# lumen query string filter

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am having a REST API which can be used to sort multiple fields on a given collection. Is there any way to convert these into the query string of a URL? For example:

```
https://example.com/users?sortBy=createdAt:asc,name:desc
```

This will sort the users by createdAt and then name.

Does Lumen/Laravel have any default way of converting these into query string parameters for filtering them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use arrays as query parameters.

Something like:

https://example.com/users?sortby[createdAt]=asc&sortyby[name]=desc

will give you this object:

```
{
    "sortby": {
        "createdAt": "asc",
        "name": "desc"
    }
}
```

So now you can easily iterate through this object and build up your query builder for example.

Comment: This will work, but the redundancy has to be avoided in URL. for example sortby used in the URL will increase if parameters to be searched increases.